# Load test using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

how to do load test using `JMETER` to find the maximum users that the application can handle? I had done load testing for the gaming application using `JMETER` I have a summary report , aggregate report and graph are generated using available plugins. How to find the load capacity with these reports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Load testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) is not about finding the maximum users the application can handle, load testing is about checking whether the application can support the anticipated amount of users.

If you want to identify the maximum, you need to go for [stress testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) to wit start with the anticipated number of users (or just from 1 virtual user) and gradually increase the load until response time starts exceeding the acceptable value or errors start occurring.

- At the beginning you will see that the number of users increases, throughput increases and response time remains the same
- At some point you will see that throughput doesn't increase although the number of users is increasing, it means you passed the [saturation point](http://hd-performance.blogspot.com/2010/05/saturation-point.html) - the point of maximum performance, this is probably what you're looking for
- If you continue increasing the number of virtual users you will see that response time is increasing and throughput is either remains the same or decreases - this indicates the [bottleneck](https://blog.qatestlab.com/2018/04/17/testing-system-bottlenecks/)

More information: [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough/)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Then for load testing, what are the factors that need to considered to find that the application can handle the anticipated amount of users.

Comment: You should know it already from the non-functional requirements or service-level agreements. If there is no information - go for stress testing directly

Comment: as a favor, can u mention specifically... Plss